# Projection of a Sphere onto a Cylinder

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

> [image: Diagram of the problem]
>
> Source: Tristan Needham VDG

I've been trying to determine the metric for the projection of a sphere onto a cylinder, where $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi R$ and $-R \leq y \leq R$

The book says to reason geometrically that $d\hat{s}^2 = \frac{\,dy^2}{R^2-y^2} + (R^2-y^2)\,dx^2$ where $d\hat{s}$ is the infinitesimal displacement on the sphere.

I keep getting stuck at trying to determine what the individual changes $d\hat{s_1}$ due to $dx$ and $d\hat{s_2}$ due to $dy$ are, but I keep ending up with an $R^2$ in the denominator of the $dx$ term and an $R^2$ in the numerator of the $dy$ term.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've beens staring at this one for quite a while!

**EDIT**: I have discovered in the Errata for the book that my original solution was actually correct. Thank you everyone for taking the time to address my question!

Comment: If $x$ is the angle, it should go from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are distance measurements then you **need** those extra factors of $R^2.$ The formula you wrote is clearly wrong at the equator, where $y=0$, because the given formula then says $d\hat{s} = \frac1{R^2}(dy)^2 + R^2(dx)^2,$ whereas the correct equation (at the equator) is $(d\hat{s})^2 = (dy)^2 + (dx)^2.$ Also, $-2\pi R \leq x \leq 2\pi R$ is a total distance $4\pi R,$ which would wrap around the cylinder twice.

Comment: @DavidK, now that I think about it, you are right, in the limiting case near the equator that extra factor has to be there. I suppose there's a typo in the book? Thanks for the response, really appreciate it. And yes, the bounds on $x$ were a typo on my part. It should in fact range from $0$ to $2\pi R$ only

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the correction, have edited it to be consistent. That was a typo on my part!

Comment: This still makes no sense to me. Is $x$ a coordinate on the $x$-axis or is it really $\theta$? What book is this?

Comment: @TedShifrin this is Tristan Needham's "Visual Differential Geometry and Forms". $x$ is actually the distance traveled along a latitude of the cylinder, so in terms of $\theta$ it would be $R \theta$

Comment: You’re also missing the square in $d\hat s^2$. I think cylindricsl coordinates are less confusing. I actually don’t understand what  “metric for the projection” is supposed to mean. Is the goal to see that the projection is area-preserving?

Comment: The final goal is to demonstrate that the projection is area-preserving and also show the area of a polar cap geometrically. By metric, in terms of $dx$ and $dy$ as defined on the cylinder, the question asks for $d\hat{s}$, the displacement on the sphere

Comment: I love this book!

Comment: @Buraian it's such a wonderful book that I hesitate to consider that this question has a typo! Although the book *is* quite new relatively speaking.

Comment: Your formula is the metric tensor, not $ds$.

Comment: Send me a message in this [room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120404/buraians-not-so-secret-hideout) if you want to discuss the book. I too am going through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [image]

In the above picture, suppose I fix $y$ and rotate $r$ by $d \theta$, what is the length gained?

$ \delta s= r' \delta \theta$

For that, we go back to highschool trignometry and draw a diagram:

> [image]
> We can write:

$$ r' = \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} \tag{1}$$

Putting that back in the distance equation:

$$ \delta s = \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} \delta \theta$$

Or,

$$ \frac{ \delta s}{\delta \theta} = \sqrt{R^2-y^2} \tag{2}$$

Next we need to check how much distance is gained when $y$ is increased, in (1), we can take the differential:
$$ \delta r'= \frac{-2y \delta y}{\sqrt{R^2 -y^2}} \tag{3}$$

What does $\delta r'$ represent? The shrinking of the radius of circle as we increase $y$:

[image]

The arclength (light blue) should be:

$$\delta s = \sqrt{\delta y^2-\delta r^2}
 \tag{4}$$

Using (3) in (4) , we have:

$$ \delta s = \frac{ R^2\delta y}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}$$

Or,

$$ \frac{\delta s}{\delta y} = \frac{R^2}{\sqrt{R^2 -y^2}}$$

Since geometrically we can see that the metric is orthogonal (page-37), we can write:

$$ ds^2 =  \frac{R^2dy^2}{R^2-y^2} +  (R^2-y^2)d \theta^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Vectorially,

$ \vec{r_C }= ( R \cos(x), R \sin(x) , y ) $

Its projection on the sphere is

$ \vec{r_S} = ( \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} \cos(x), \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} \sin(x) , y ) $

Then, taking the differentials,

$ d \vec{r_S} = \left( \dfrac{d \vec{r_S}}{dx} \right) dx + \left( \dfrac{d \vec{r_S}}{dy} \right) dy $

and this evaluates to

$ d \vec{r_S} = \left( \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} (-sin(x) ), \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} \cos(x), 0  \right) dx + \left( -\dfrac{y\cos(x)}{\sqrt{R^2 - y^2}} , - \dfrac{y\sin(x)}{\sqrt{R^2 - y^2}} , 1 \right) dy $

Since the vector multiplying $dx$ is orthogonal to the vector multiplying $dy$ , then

$ \|d \vec{r_S} \|^2 = (dx)^2 (R^2 - y^2) + (dy)^2 ( \dfrac{y^2}{R^2 - y^2} + 1 ) $

And this simplifies to

$ \| d \vec{r_S} \|^2 = (dx)^2 (R^2 - y^2) + (dy)^2 \dfrac{R^2}{R^2 - y^2} $

Comment: It seems that the $dx$ part of this formula breaks down at the equator, as mentioned in another comment. When $y=0$, the metric should simplify to $dx^2 + dy^2$, right? Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: You are right! @AliShakir